# Python - Writing to C:/Program Files

Tags: python

I have an Installer executable file that Installs a Python executable (py2exe) into Program Files/SoftwareFolderGoesHere, and the Python executable is a game patcher that is meant to download the latest patch into the directory it is being executed from. However, the Python executable is denied permission to write to Program Files, unless it is always Run as Administrator using Right Click -> Run as Administrator. Is there any way to get my patching system to be able to write to Program Files without being Run as Administrator? If not, are there any programming languages that -do- allow this? Or is the best alternative to write the patching data to an appdata folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Account Control - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).

Answer (score 3):

There is no programming language that as a feature defeats the Windows security model. The solution is to set the programme to always be run as administrator.